# Adjective/slang that describes a person who urgently needs to go to the toilet

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, slang, idiom-requests, colloquialisms

We say **hungry** if someone wants to **eat**, **thirsty** if someone wants to **drink**, and **sleepy** if someone wants to **sleep**.

What's the adjective/slang used to describe a person who has a desire to go  to the toilet urgently, other than "I want to take a piss/dump".

Do we have such a word in the casual day-to-day speech? I am looking for an informal word that can be used with friends.

Comment: What language has a single word for this?

Comment: 'Bursting' was once used in very colloquial and near-childlike speech in the UK. "I'm bursting [for a pee]." I'd avoid it nowadays.

Comment: I have to **go**. (Alternatively, and perhaps less genteel, "My eyeballs are floating.")

Comment: Well, I guess it's Depends.

Comment: What @RobJarvis said. But note that when it's a *male* speaking, *I have to **go*** (often with heavy stress on the highlighted word) is quite likely to elicit the response ***Number one or number two**?* (a "tinkle" or a "poo"). But ***I'm bursting*** would invariably be interpreted as "number one" there. For the second possibility, from the movie *Rat Race*, there's Kimberly's response after being offered a jam-jar to pee in when she's "**taken short**" during a long car drive: *Dad, I don't have to pee! It's number two! **I'm prairie-dogging it!*** Ew!

Comment: @tchrist: We do actually have ***gravid*** as a fairly "dedicated" adjective for "full of **baby** (or **eggs**) urgently needing to be ejected from the body". Plus we have ***constipated*** in this general area, so it wouldn't be ridiculous to have a specific term in English. I'm doubtful though.

Comment: Is it ok to say I'm so stuck? I guess I heard it in a movie.

Comment: "I'm desperate" is sometimes used in Br English but only in context, for example "Where's the loo, I'm desperate". However the fuller phrases such as "I'm desperate for a pee" are more common without context. I do not believe that there is a true adjective equivalent to "hungry" or "thirsty". I'm also fairly sure that hunger and thirst are unusual in having adjectives that describe the condition of having an urgent need. There is, again to my knowledge, no simple adjective describing someone who is desperate for air.

Comment: Are you talking about getting rid of solid waste or liquid waste? A slang expression for somebody who really needs to do the former is "prairie dogging," although it also has a more common sense.

Comment: I've always been partial to "My back teeth are floatin'" Not a single word, but it gets the point across.

Comment: There are lots of colourful metaphors for needing a poo, like "touching cloth" https://97rockonline.com/my-50-favorite-euphemisms-for-taking-a-dump/

Answer (score 1):

"Bursting" is used colloquially and widely in the part of the UK I come from. I strongly disagree with Edwin's assertion that it is "near-childlike".

"To be desperate for"is also widely used.
https://www.reddit.com/r/britishproblems/comments/aacdwa/being_desperate_for_the_toilet_after_sitting_for/
https://www.thesouthernreporter.co.uk/lifestyle/cars/drivers-risking-huge-fines-and-points-going-toilet-motorway-1422240#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Is it ok to say I'm so stuck? Where is the toilet? I heard it in an American movie.

Comment: @acme - In British English it would mean nothing. In American English, according to Urban Dictionary, "I'm stuck" means "I'm tired" or under the influence of drugs.  (Presumably because of being stuck with a needle when injecting drugs).  https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stuck

Comment: "13 May 2016 - Eight of the 25 children (a third) used 'bursting' to describe how they felt regarding going to the toilet. 'Bursting' is a term generally used by children in Ireland when feeling urgency or on the verge of involuntary incontinence as opposed to “need to go” which is typically used for bladder fullness."
by M Tatlow-Golden - ‎2017 ' [[SAGE Journals](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bursting+to+go+to%22&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&oq=%22bursting+to+go+to%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6846j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

Answer (score 1):

In US slang, there is **(to be) busting** and the verb *bust* is a variant of *burst*.

> *spec.* To be desperate for the toilet. Chiefly with *for* or *to*. Also *to be ready to bust.* - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25272?rskey=Z2AiNZ&result=1&isAdvanced=true#firstMatch)*

Apparently, it is still used in British slang also as *OED* provides examples from recent British publications. Here are the last two citations:

From *Mixmag* (a British electronic dance and clubbing magazine), 1994:

> Rob was busting for a widdle the whole time, but when they eventually let him visit the can he was surrounded by a brace of coppers watching him.

From the book *Lullaby* by C. Seeber (a British author from London), 2007:

> Can I just use your loo quickly? I'm busting.

I've also come across the phrase **caught short** which appears to be mainly used in Australian slang. *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28817?redirectedFrom=caught%20short#eid1368152673)* definition:

> To be caught by an urgent need to urinate or defecate, especially when there are no toilet facilities available.

*[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/short)* mentions *be caught short* as British informal and provides the definition below, plus a funny example:

> Urgently need to urinate or defecate. 
> *'On one occasion, after being caught short during a particularly exciting match, he merrily urinated over the heads of the fans sitting below'*